# How to maximise revenue from limited number of advertisers

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, affiliate

Suppose you have a page that ranks very well for a very specific subject (and gets a reasonable amount of traffic).

You don't provide what the visitors are looking for but there are **just 3** companies in the marketplace who do.

What strategies could you use to place advertisements on that page to get the maximum revenue?

Some initial thoughts

- Adsense - obvious, but I thought this was better suited to long tail situations rather than a very targeted traffic with a limited number of potential advertisers?
- Affiliate Links (assuming some/all of the 3 companies do these, but what if they don't?)
- Auction off advertising space directly with the 3 companies involved.
  In which case would you do either as

  - 'Sealed bids' - where they get to place one offer, highest wins. No bidding war but chance to get more than 'market price' as determined via auction.
  - Do as traditional auction where bidders can see whats been bid, but not by whom - could introduce bidding war.

Answer (score 1):

I would definately choose to sell the ads directly to the customer, since you would cut out the middleman.

Why not sell ads to all three of them and just create a bannerrotation?

Comment: Thinking you could segment by having a "Premium banner" a bit bigger etc than the rest, then smaller ones for the others.